# ZendFramework 2 - layout load with database query

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have the layout.phtml file, where the certain part of the html code loads `<?php echo $this->content; ?>` to load the normal content sent by the controllers. 
The problem is that before this I have a part of the code (an envelope icon with the number of new messages) where I need it every time the page is updated, it checks the database for new messages.

How can I do this using Zend Framework 2?

Answer (score 0):

There's direct no connection db and view and this's good. So will write a view helper to get messages. Here you can get some help from [documenttation](http://zendframework.github.io/zend-view/helpers/advanced-usage/). If you fail in any part let us know so we can help.